# iframe mac compatibility issue? CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, macos, web

I am developing a website and this is giving Mac compatibility error like `iframe not supported`, especially safari. I also have issues on other browsers like Commodo Chrome, Novo  Chrome, but it is working on Chrome, Safari Windows, Mozilla Windows.

What I want to know is:

- Is there any MASTER.css files that make the website compatible with every browser including mac?
- The serious problem is in iframe displaying at mac OS safari and all other browsers

Comment: adding some css isn't going to magically make an `<iframe>` work.

Comment: no recently 2 months ago i faced that but then i added a style sheet that was on internet but i forget its name that sheet resolved the issue and the sheet description was **this style sheet make website all browser compatible** and resolved all mac issues

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions

> - Is there any MASTER.css files that make the website compatible with every browser including mac?

No, there is not.  You can look at some JavaScript libraries that can help fill in the gaps, but there is no MASTER.css that will make a website look exactly the same on every browser.

You can take a look at some web frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for some help getting your site to look similar on most browsers.

> - The serious problem is in iframe displaying at mac OS safari and all other browsers

What isn't working?  There are several reasons why an iFrame isn't rendering correctly on different browsers.  Off the top of my head, here are some reasons why:

- The page being displayed in the iFrame has a Same Origin policy
- The iFrame's src attribute has JavaScript instead of a URL which works for *some* browsers but not all (I've seen it, people do it.  Don't know why, but they do)
- The browser has security policies that prevent iFraming
- The CSS in the iFramed window is not compatible with the browser
- The iFramed window uses JavaScript that causes the page to Error

Basically, without more information about *what* is not displaying correctly, there is no way to know *why*.

Comment: why css ..my iframe works on win and every browsers and on mac my iframe have content as i inspected but not visible  to me speacialy in safari

Comment: Can you post some pictures of what you're seeing?  Also, maybe some of the HTML so I can help troubleshoot what's going on?